# Pass data from res.write() to formidable filename

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I use **node** to allow users to upload a file:

```
var http = require('http');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.url == '/fileupload') {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
      var oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
      var newpath = 'team_1_uploads/' + files.filetoupload.name + files.filetoupload.token;
      fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.write('            FILE UPLOADED!');
        res.end();
      });
 });
  } else {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write('<div align="center">');
    res.write('<html>');
    res.write('<body>');
    res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
    res.write('<input id="file_input" type="file" name="filetoupload" style="margin-left: 100px; margin-bottom: 10px; color: transparent"><br>');
    res.write('<input id="submit_button" type="submit">');
    res.write('</form>');
    res.write('</body>');
    res.write('</html>');
    res.write('</div>');
    return res.end();
  }
}).listen(3131);
```

As you can see, I am trying to append a token onto the filename. The upload button gets served by node through an iframe on the front-end. I can pass the token to res.write() using postMessage, by adding the following script to res.write():

```
res.write("<script>window.addEventListener('message', function(event) { document.getElementById('file_input').dataset.token = event.data; global_hold_token = event.data; })</script>");
```

This sets the token to the form element by using the data attribute on the form element. The message is received from the front end by using postMessage:

```
$('#my_frame')[0].contentWindow.postMessage(token, '*')
```

I thought I could then **parse the data attribute using formidable**. But node doesn't seem able to access the data attribute on the form element, even though it can access the name.

Answer (score 0):

The `?token=xxxxxx` is a GET parameter. You can get these from the `req` object, under the `req.query` object

http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query

So in your case, it will be in `req.query.token`

Comment: I get "Cannot read property 'token' of undefined" when using req.query.token

Comment: No luck. It seem like there should be a way to simply set the token to the data element inside the iframe using postMessage (which works), and then simply get the data attirubute from the form element in node (cannot get to work). See Edit.